# How to compare file sizes in two directories?

Tags: files, file-transfer, verification

I have copied some files to an SFTP-only server.

I want to verify that all the files arrived intact. Since the server is SFTP-only, I cannot run e.g., an MD5sum on the remote host.

I have the server mounted via GVFS/SFTP on my local machine.

There are many gigabytes of data I wish to verify. However, doing a byte-by-byte diff would be infeasible. Instead, I wish to simply compare file sizes.
Since the SSH protocol is encrypted, and therefore resistant to tampering/errors (and I have no enemies powerful enough to tamper with an SSH connection, especially for files as trifling as these,) I can safely assume that every byte that DID make it across made it across intact.
However, a truncated file is still a possibility.

How can I compare file sizes (in bytes) for a large amount of files?

Comment: Possible dup: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62140/filesize-difference-of-same-name-folders

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/166317/linux-compare-directory-structure-without-comparing-files